# Getting remote performance data using php

Tags: php, ssh

I need to find remote data such as RAM usage, swap usage, number of processors, etc, using a php script from the local computer and 10 other remote computers.

How can I go about it?

The remote computers are all running Linux, and they can run any service that is needed of the machine.

What I have in mind is that I can somehow use ssh using the PHP script. Then use top or something to find what I need.

It also needs to be a single PHP file that displays all the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will probably want to look at PHP Expect, it allows you to do something like connect to a remote host, and provide input/responses to output on the remote.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.expect.php

Comment: This sounds nice - any links?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered a monitoring suite like [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) instead of PHP? I think Nagios can give you all this data in a central web-based interface. As far as I know, it has a learning curve that is not entirely trivial, but it may still beat building a PHP solution.

Comment: +1 for Nagios. There are also a ton of tools that plugin to help you monitor w/ Nagios

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP [sockets](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php) to communicate with servers remotely via [SNMP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.snmp.php). The remote servers need to have SNMP activated and configured to provide the data you need, such as hardware info, bandwidth, disk space, swap usage, etc.